# Unable to upload excel file in php to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been trying to build a section in php file from where i can upload a excel files to the database.I did all the coding part but its not working.Data was not uploaded. So please help me.

Here is my code

This is the html part from where i will be uploading the excel file using enctype="multipart/form-data":

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-body">
    <form method="POST" action="uploads.php?y='.$y.'&m='.$m.'" style="margin-left: 100px;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select file to upload:
    <br/> <small style="color: red;">*Please attach only .xls & .xlsx files. 
   </small>
    </label>
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="width:300px; align: center;">
<br/>
<input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

PHP file uploads.php :

Data of the excel file is then sent to the php file to upload in the database, But this isn't working.

```
  require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
    require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

    $y=$_GET['y'];
    $m=$_GET['m'];
    $year=$y.'_'.$m;

   if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType))
{

    $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

    $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
    for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
    {
        $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

        foreach ($Reader as $Row) {

            $date = "";
            if(isset($Row[0])) {
                $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
            }

            $janmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[1])) {
                $janmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
            }

            $janmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[2])) {
                $janmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[2]);
            }               

            $febmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[3])) {
                $febmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[3]);
            }

            $febmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[4])) {
                $febmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[4]);
            }

            $marmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[5])) {
                $marmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[5]);
            }

            $marmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[6])) {
                $marmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[6]);
            }

            $aprmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[7])) {
                $aprmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[7]);
            }

            $aprmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[8])) {
                $aprmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[8]);
            }

            $maymin = "";
            if(isset($Row[9])) {
                $maymin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[9]);
            }

            $maymax = "";
            if(isset($Row[10])) {
                $maymax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[10]);
            }

            $junemin = "";
            if(isset($Row[11])) {
                $junemin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[11]);
            }

            $junemax = "";
            if(isset($Row[12])) {
                $junemax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[12]);
            }

            $julymin = "";
            if(isset($Row[13])) {
                $julymin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[13]);
            }

            $julymax = "";
            if(isset($Row[14])) {
                $julymax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[14]);
            }

            $augmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[15])) {
                $augmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[15]);
            }

            $augmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[16])) {
                $augmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[16]);
            }

            $sepmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[17])) {
                $sepmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[17]);
            }

            $sepmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[18])) {
                $sepmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[18]);
            }

            $octmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[19])) {
                $octmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[19]);
            }

            $octmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[20])) {
                $octmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[20]);
            }

            $novmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[21])) {
                $novmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[21]);
            }

            $novmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[22])) {
                $novmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[22]);
            }

            $decmin = "";
            if(isset($Row[23])) {
                $decmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[23]);
            }

            $decmax = "";
            if(isset($Row[24])) {
                $decmax = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[24]);
            }

            if (!empty($date)) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `$year` (janmin,janmax,febmin,febmax,marmin,marmax,aprilmin,aprilmax,maymin,maymax,junemin,junemax,julymin,julymax,augmin,augmax,sepmin,sepmax,octmin,octmax,novmin,novmax,decmin,decmax,user_id,date) 
 VALUES ('$janmin','$janmax','$febmin','$febmax','$marmin','$marmax','$aprmin','$aprmax','$maymin','$maymax','$junemin','$junemax','$julymin','$julymax','$augmin','$augmax','$sepmin','$sepmax','$octmin','$octmax','$novmin','$novmax','$decmin','$decmax','$user_id','$date')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                if (! empty($result)) {
                    $type = "success";
                    $message = "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
                    echo $type.'<br />'.$message;

                } else {
                    $type = "error";
                    $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                    echo $type.'<br />'.$message;
                }
            }



        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: ___But this isn't working.___ But that is not really any help to someone trying to provide remote support like we are. Tell us what **is** doing! Tell us what is in NOT doing! Show us any errors! Look at the log files to see if there are any errors!!! ___Then maybe we can helpp___

Comment: By the way `mysqli_query()` returns TRUE on success.. so no need for `!empty()`

Comment: So @B001ᛦ means this line `if (! empty($result)) {` will not a reliable test of success OR failure

Comment: OK, Thank you very much for your replies. I removed     if(! empty($result)) {    part. But still its not working. Can anyone please help me if there anything i can add or modify to the code above.